# c program giving 32767 for letters

Tags: c

My C program is giving the number "32767" when I enter a letter, but when I enter an integer it tells me the number that I entered.

why will my program not tell me what letters I entered? why is it giving me the number "32767"?

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int number;

    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    printf("Integer entered by you is %d\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf() returns int.  Do not ignore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `scanf` doesn't find what it's looking for (in this case, an `int`), it will simply return without modifying whatever gets passed in. In other words, `scanf` won't change `number`, so it'll have it's old value, which, in this case, is undefined (since it's not initialized).

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is "undefined behaviour", which pretty much means "anything can happen". The value in `number`, in particular, can have any value, because it has not been initialized. If you initialize it `int number = 42;` it will (probably) print `42`, but I'm not sure that's guaranteed.

Comment: "probably" - are you unsure if `scanf` won't touch `number`?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if the standard guarantees under all circumstances that it won't be touched - it certainly will be touched if you enter '12b', but next thing will go bang.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `printf()` to display characters and `scanf()` to get that data, you must point that it's a character, using "char" instead of "int" and use `"%c"` instead of `"%d"`.

Something like this (I still used the "number" variable and the description in the `printf()` about the " integer":

```c
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    char number;

    printf("Enter an integer\n");
    scanf("%c",&number);

    printf("Integer entered by you is %c\n", number);

    return 0;
}
```